# Python Re module: find words after specific word

Tags: python, python-re

I would like to search words after specific words with re module. (without using list comprehensions)

```
sentence = "I like you, I like your smile, I like stack o v e r flow"

# expected outcome
['you', 'your smile', 'stack o v e r flow']
```

I managed to get a single word after 'I like', but couldn't figure out how to get the whole sentence when there are different numbers of words.

```
# my code
re.compile(r'I like (\w+)').findall(sentence)

# my output
['you', 'your', 'stack']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this regexp I get the correct output:

```py
sentence = "I like you, I like your smile, I like stack o v e r flow"
re.compile(r'I like ([\w\s]+)').findall(sentence)
```

You need to consider an optional space (`\s`) together with the word  character(`\w`). This pattern occurs at least once (`[\w\s]+`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `[\w ]+` instead of `\w+` to account for white spaces. Also you can use the comma to separate chunks of the sentence you want to analyze:

```py
>>> re.findall("I like ([\w ]+),*", sentence)

['you', 'your smile', 'stack o v e r flow']
```

Comment: The square brackets list all characters that will be caught, on which I applied a `+` qualifier to indicate that I want at least one match. so `[\w +]` will catch "you" or " " or "you smile" or any sub-strings with a character, an underscore and a space.